# Convolution of independent distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Let F be a distribution on $R$ and X be a randomvariable with distribution F.
If $x\geq0,$ $\overline G(x)=P(X>x|X\geq0)$ (i.e. conditional distribution), then $\overline{G*G}(x)=P(X_1+X_2>x|X_1\geq0,X_2\geq0).$
Here, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent copies of X.
How can I show this statement?

Comment: Do you mean $\bar G\ast\bar G(x)$?